# Undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.Asset.loadAsync')

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-development, react-native-elements

I'm creating a project with React-Native, and currently when I try to compile my code I get an error saying `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo_.Asset.loadAsync')`

I'm not entirely sure what had caused this, for I entered a lot of code prior to compiling the project. However, from what I gathered this may have something to do with the fonts I'm importing?

currently this is what my code looks like for importing the font.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await cacheFonts({
      georgia: require('../assets/fonts/Georgia.ttf'),
      regular: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
      light: require('../assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf'),
    });

    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me in similar code:

Install :

> npm install expo-font

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font'; 
...
...

async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
        'josefin-sans-regular': require('./assets/fonts/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf')
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't show the error-causing code. But you seem to have called in the entire module of `Expo`.

Maybe you used `import * as Expo from "expo"` and `Expo.Asset.loadAsync`

With `SDK 33`, we’re deprecating imports of most modules from the `expo` package. Each module must be installed and used.

You can run `expo install expo-asset`

```js
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
...
Asset.loadAsync(modules)
```

If you want to use it as it is now, you can use this module. [expo-codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-codemod)